ASP.NET Core Blazor - bind-Value not updating field
I'm new to Blazor and I'm trying to build a very simple form with it. The method OnInitialized works fine, meaning after rendering the page the value "Hello World!" is shown in the text box.
However, if I change the value and submit the form the value does update the field userInput. Does anybody know the reason for it and how to fix it?
Cheers!
@page "/simpleform"

<PageTitle>TestPage</PageTitle>
<h3>Einfaches Formular</h3>

<EditForm Model="userInput" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="test">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputText">Text eingeben</label>
        <InputText id="inputText" class="form-control" @bind-Value="userInput.InputText" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Absenden</button>
</EditForm>


@if (submittedText != null)
{
    <p>Du hast eingegeben: @submittedText</p>
}

@code {
    private UserInputModel userInput = new UserInputModel();
    private string? submittedText;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        userInput.InputText = "Hello World!";
    }

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        submittedText = userInput.InputText;
    }

    public class UserInputModel
    {
        public string? InputText { get; set; }
    }
}

using Test.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


Hmmm, from this demo I can see the both userInput and submittedText are updated.

@nicesbrot is your project blazor web assembly or blazor server?

What is the rendermode type of your Blazor application? Is it SSR or InteractiveServer?

Thanks for responding guys. I added the code form my Program.cs. I use a Blazor Server Application with InteractiveServer render mode.

@YongShun I agree, in BlazorFiddle things are working just fine.

https://github.com/nicesbrot/BlazorServerTest
I published the whole thing on my GitHub.

Ensure that you have applying the render mode to the entire app.
This should resolve the component from re-rendering and result in the value of userInput.InputText being reset to "Hello World!".
App.razor
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />


That fixed it. Thank you! :) Why is this not set per default though?

You're welcome. For your question, maybe I am not correct, based on what I know that the render mode is opt-in (optional) through the pipeline in Program.cs (AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()). And the render mode could be applied to certain components only @rendermode. So, this may be complex for Blazor to set it default. Maybe this feature can be suggested on the GitHub and see what is the developers' feedback and concern.

"Why is this not set per default?"  It's set based on which template and template options you choose when creating a solution.  You chose Per Page/Component, so that's what you got.  It's a fairly common mistake to make when you first start using Blazor.
